# How to delete apk after installation in android

Tags: android, apk

I have written an app updater library that downloads an updated apk from a remote host if there is a new version available. The user is then prompted to install the apk. I was wondering if there is any way to listen for the install to complete so that I could delete the apk after the install? Also, the app receiving the update is the one currently running and I don't know if this means the app is killed when the update install occurs.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT

Comment: Could you make an example for how to implement the above functionality or give a resource that gives an example please? I don't think I'm using it correctly.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroidclient/blob/833ae329e45905b36c60af9f8f11176d77df5280/app/src/main/java/org/fdroid/fdroid/installer/DefaultInstallerActivity.java -- basically, with `EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT`, you use `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()`, as you might with other actions (e.g., `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`).

Comment: "Also, the app receiving the update is the one currently running and I don't know if this means the app is killed when the update install occurs." -- yes. You know when the installation is completed if/when the user chooses to run your app again.

Comment: you can delete all apks on launch of app

Answer (score 1):

As [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) said in the comments I needed to use `startActivityForResult` and then `onActivityResult` will get called the next time the app opens. Here's what I did.

```
@Override
public void onInstallClick() {
    File file = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), mParameters.getPackageName() + ".apk");

    if (!file.exists())
        return;

    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(uri);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INSTALL);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_INSTALL) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            File file = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), mParameters.getPackageName() + ".apk");

            if (file.exists())
                file.delete();
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```